# How can I access method in object when pointer of object is stored in vector?

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

In C++, with Visual Studio Code,

I made class Person.
I made a `vector <Person*> phonebook`.
I constructed an object `Person newperson` and pushed it in my vector `phonebook`
And I want to access `newperson.print()`.
So I wrote `phonebook[i]->print` but it shows a runtime error.

I thought it was a copy constructor problem, but after I added it, it was the same. And I also tried to separate by constructing a new dummy object, but it doesn't work either. How can I access to object's method through object's pointer stored in vector?

```
Person(const Person &oldperson)
        {
            firstname = oldperson.firstname;
            lastname = oldperson.lastname;
            phonenumber = oldperson.phonenumber;
        }
//This is my copy constructor,


void PrintAll()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < phonebook.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << "Hello " << i << endl;//it runs
        Person personprinter = Person(*phonebook[i]);
        cout << "Hello 2" << endl;//it does not run
        personprinter.Print();
    }
}
//This is my method where I will call object's method.
```

Expected: `.Print()` runs.

Actual: `Person personprinter = Person(*phonebook[i]);` doesn't run.

Comment: Why do you store pointers and not the objects (persons) in your phonebook?

Comment: Can you add `cout << (void *) phonebook[i] << endl;` before the line and look if there is a `0`?

Comment: @mch no there is a 0x65fe44
if I change my code like:

        cout << (void *) phonebook[i] << endl;

        Person personprinter = Person(*phonebook[i]);

Comment: @jo Phonebook is declared in global variable : vector <Person *> phonebook;

Comment: @vahancho i thought that it would be space effictive and It also was a constraint for a project.

Comment: show how you add items into the phonebook

Comment: If you want to store pointers, you need to store pointers to objects whose lifetimes are long enough. Usually, those objects are created with `new`.

Comment: do the persons have a life outside of the phone book? Eg if you also have a email-book seperate from the phonebook then storing pointers to persons might be fine, but then consider to use smart pointers instead (probably `weak_ptr`). If however your `Person` is merely an entry in the phonebook and has no meaning otherwise, then you should definitely have a vector of `Person`s not a vector of pointers

Answer (score 0):

I think we need definition of phonebook and also to see the way you added object in it.

The object you added in phonebook have gone out of scope thus they have been deleted (you did not do a new to build the object).

Then you are using a pointer to a deleted object.

```
{
    Person newperson = Person(nameinarray[0], nameinarray[1], phonenumber);
    phonebook.push_back(&newperson);
}// closing the curly brace here calls delete on newperson  
// pointer in phonebook now points to a deleted object
```

VS

```
{
    Person* newperson = new Person(nameinarray[0], nameinarray[1], phonenumber);
    phonebook.push_back(newperson);
}  
// pointer in phone book is still valid
```

Comment: Phonebook is declared in global variable : vector <Person *> phonebook;
and object was added like
Person newperson = Person(nameinarray[0], nameinarray[1], phonenumber);
phonebook.push_back(&newperson);

Comment: So you are in first case : the object newperson lives until you go out of scope  i.e: on closing curly-bracket '}'

Comment: in order to make your question clear add declaration of phonebook and complete code filling the phonebook to your post

Comment: You were right! I solved my problem with 'new' keyword. Thank you for help.